# Mesh has a snail shell distorsion around a Bezier Circle

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have issues trying to create some stairs with curve modifier.

Tried to work with a spiral curve but it doesn't really give me the result i expect. Also tried playing with the curve settings but I can't find what's wrong.

Blend file: http://madgoat-studio.com/test.blend

Comment: You haven't said what the issue is.  Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: Xtremity, If you're looking from top orthographic view you will see that the modifier deforms the mesh into a snail shell. https://gyazo.com/e473a5ac8661a3657aaf746cbec9e9a6

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve?  Its a bit unclear as to what the exact issue is.

Comment: Timaroberts, to make the issue more obvious, if you increase the count in the array modifier you get this: https://gyazo.com/33a04ebd969f5d7a828844263c6b8b64 I want it to not deform like that, those stairs will be inside a cilinder and not a cone.

Comment: It's probably because the angle of the stairs relative to the curve is a little odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file, then

1. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all
2. <kbd>Alt-R</kbd> to clear rotations
3. Select stairs only
4. <kbd>R</kbd>, -90, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to rotate the stairs to their proper orientation

If you want to rotate the stair afterwards, remember to rotate the spline along with it.